# Merge table on either of the 2 columns in pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, merge

I am working on python to merge a table using pandas, but I am having little trouble. Here's the problem.

I have 2 tables_A and table_B. I have two columns on table_A say "one", "two". I have two column on table_B say "one","three". column "one" in table_B has some values which maps to column "one" in table_A and some values which maps to column "two" in table_A. How can I map values in python similar to query:

```
Select * from Table_A a, Table_B b
where a.one = b.one or a.two=b.one
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider a concatenation with merge which would translate your SQL query as `OR` is often analogous to a `UNION`:

```
pd.concat([pd.merge(table_A, table_B, on='one'),
           pd.merge(table_A, table_B, left_on='two', right_on='one')])
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to recreate one of the columns from table_A in table_B.

I will flesh out a case. A is a DataFrame of first and last names, and you want to fill in each person's "score."  B is a DataFrame of scores with just one name associated - it could be the first or last.  We can use A to create a map for the ambiguous name column in B.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'firstName': ['Adam', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
            'lastName': ['Axe', 'Button', 'Cobb']})

# B's name column has two first names and one last name.
B = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Adam', 'Bob', 'Cobb'],
                 'score': ['A', 'B', 'C']})

# A mappable Series
s = A.set_index('firstName').lastName  
B['lastName'] = B.name.replace(s)  
cols = ['lastName', 'score']
A.merge(B[cols], on='lastName')
```