# Pandas merge with WHERE-like condition and either/or columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have a Pandas dataframe `names` containing one column with names:

```
names
A
B
C
D
```

I have another Pandas dataframe `results` that contains match data where names can appear in two columns, that is, `wname` or `lname`. Furthermore this dataframe contains an `Id` and a `result` column:

```
id   wname  lname   result
1    A      B       X
1    B      C       Y
1    C      D       Z
2    C      D       Y
2    D      A       Y
2    A      B       Z
```

Furthermore I have a dictionary `pdict` that for each `name` in the `names` dataframe contains the `id` from the `results` dataframe that I am interested in:

```
{A: 1, B: 1, C: 2, D: 2}
```

I now want to merge the two dataframes `names` and `results` as follows:

- all the rows of `results` should be joined to the respective `name`, if the `name` appears in either the `wname` column or in the `lname` column of `results`
- additionally, only the rows of `results` should be joined if for the respective `name`, the `id` column is relevant. this can be looked up in the `pdict` dictionary.

The result should look as follows:

```
names   id   wname  lname   result
A       1    A      B       X
B       1    A      B       X
B       1    B      C       Y
C       2    C      D       Y
D       2    C      D       Y
D       2    D      A       Y
```

I want to do this as efficient as possible, since I have several thousand names and results that need to be merged.

I know how to use `pd.merge` to join on one column. But how can I do this on either `wname` or `lname` column? And how can I join only rows from the right side (`results`) that are associated to the `name` in the dict?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552785/merge-table-on-either-of-the-2-columns-in-pandas), I now know how to do the join on either/or the `wname` and `lname` columns. My final issue is then the lookup in the dict. I could do this in a post-processing step, but for performance reasons, I think it would be much better, if the unnecessary rows from `results` would not be merged in the first place. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the data based on condition and store it in a dataframe after merging i.e

```
pdict = {"A": 1, "B": 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 2}
df2['id'] = df2['names'].map(pdict)
df = df2.merge(df)
df3 = df[(df['names']==(df['wname'])) | (df['names'] ==  df['lname'])]
```

Output :

```
  names  id wname lname result
0      A   1     A     B      X
3      B   1     A     B      X
4      B   1     B     C      Y
6      C   2     C     D      Y
9      D   2     C     D      Y
10     D   2     D     A      Y
```

You can reset the index using `df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)`

Hope it helps

Comment: this was not the exact solution, but adding the `id` from the dict to the dataframe via the `map` function helped me to solve the issue. i could then use this column as additiontaly join-column. thank you!